# PyQt5 Move a QTableWidget from a cell into another one

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a 6x1 (6 rows, 1 columns) QTableWidget table in a PyQt5 application.

As the program starts all table's cells are filled up with a QTableWidgetItem with a grey background

```
self.shaftsTable = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
# table setups (...)

for i in range(self.nf):
    for j in range(self.nc):
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(200,200,200))
        self.shaftsTable.setItem(i, j, item)
```

Then a QtWidgets.QListWidget is placed in the lowest cell (row 5, column 0)

```
el = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Window)
self.shaftsTable.setCellWidget(5, 0, el)
```

Assume the table would simulate an elevator path through 6 floors: an elevator is a QtWidgets.QListWidget that contains a list of all the passenger currently in the elevator; elevator starts from the lowest floor, hence it is placed at position (5,0) in the table.

I want to move the elevator from cell (5,0) to cell (4,0), that is, after moving from the lowest floor to the next, the elevator will be only in cell (4,0) and not in cell (5,0).

The following won't work because removeCellWidget() will delete the object definitively also from cell (4,0):

```
el = self.shaftsTable.cellWidget(5, 0)
self.shaftsTable.setCellWidget(4, 0, el)
self.shaftsTable.removeCellWidget(5, 0)
```

I didn't found any easy function to do what I need in PyQt documentation http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html

I tried to make a copy (with copy.deepcopy()) of elevator, place the copy in cell (4,0) and then delete the original elevator in cell (5,0) but copy.deepcopy() fails on QtWidgets.QListWidget.

Have you got any idea or suggestion? (I'm sure there is one or more ways to solve my problems but, as newby, I cannot figure out one)

Answer (score 0):

Quotation from here https://forum.qt.io/topic/61590/take-a-widget-from-a-qtablewidget

> ## Take a widget from a QTableWidget
>
> When you use setCellWidget the QTableWidget will own the widget.
>   Reading the doc, there doesn't seems to be a way to take back ownership as it seems
>   cellWidget() only allows access to it not to take it back so to speak.
>
> So a way is to create function that can create the widgets as you want and
>   simply recreate the widgets when you want to "swap" them as
>   you cannot really make a copy as such.
>
> So you could make a function that takes widget and copy some data
>   from it and create new one with those data
>   or create a new with default value if widget is not supplied.

---

So, there is no way to gain the ownership of a QTableWidget back from a cell of a QTableWidget in order to move it to another cell.

The only solution is to make a copy of the QTableWidget you want to move, place the copy into the destination cell (in my case cell (4,0)), then delete the original QTableWidget object from the origin cell (in my case cell (5,0)).

```
new_el = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Window)
el = self.shaftsTable.cellWidget(5, 0)

# copy contents of el into new_el with a custom function:
def unloadAllPassengers(el):
    unloaded = []
    for _ in range(el.count()):
        unloaded.append(el.takeItem(0))
    return unloaded

def loadPassengersAsQListWidgetItemArray(el, qListWidgetItemArray):
    for i in range(len(qListWidgetItemArray)):
        el.addItem(qListWidgetItemArray[i])

loadPassengersAsQListWidgetItemArray(new_el, unloadAllPassengers(el))

self.shaftsTable.setCellWidget(5, 0, None)
self.shaftsTable.setCellWidget(4, 0, new_el)
# an elevator is in cell (4,0) whlist "el" does not exists anymore
# problem solved
```